# How to change network device ipv4 address in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

I am writing a kernel module that at some point if directed will change the ipv4 address of a given interface. For example:

If the eth0 device currently has an ipv4 address of 192.168.1.1  .I am looking for how to change the ipv4 address to 192.168.5.1  .This is just an example of my desired output.

I have been looking through the linux/inetdevice.h as well as the linux/netdevice.h and can't seem to put the process together.

Comment: just curiosity: why do you use kernel module for this?

Comment: It is for my research project, the goal is to have a kernel that has some added features without having a user program constantly running. It will receive a variety of commands and based on the commands react and make the required alterations to the system.

Comment: You can inspect ifconfig source, this should help. Or better - use gdb to attach while changing IP. You will see what is going on. Next use http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ for inspecting kernel part

Comment: Thanks for that, it help a lot! I ended up getting it work!

Comment: Post the answer then!